# Summation with $\tan^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I have to calculate

$$\sum_{1 \le i <j <k \le n}^{} \arctan\left(\dfrac{n}{i} \right) \arctan\left(\dfrac{n}{j} \right)\arctan\left(\dfrac{n}{k} \right) $$

We notice for any positive number $x$, we have

$$\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2i}\log\left(\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right) = \Im\log(1 + ix)$$

We can rewrite the sum at hand as

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}\frac{n}{k} = \Im\left[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \log\left(1 + \frac{n}{k}\right) \right]
$$

but I can;t go on.

Comment: What do you actually mean by *calculate*? If *finding a reasonably simple closed form*, I doubt it exists. If *finding the asymptotic behaviour as $n\to +\infty$*, that is manageable.

Comment: you are right, I actually have to calculate the asymptotic behaviour, but I was trying to find a closed form. I guess that I was unable to find a close form

Comment: if $A$ the above summation, actually we have to calculate the limit of $\frac {A}{n^3}$

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

About the asymptotic behaviour: we may replace $\arctan\frac{n}{a}$ with $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac{a}{n}$ in order to only deal with values of the arctangent function over the interval $I=[0,1]$. Over such interval $\arctan(x)=x-\Theta(x^3)$, hence the main term of the asymptotic behaviour is the same as the main term of
$$ \frac{\pi^3}{8}\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}\left(1-\frac{2i}{\pi n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2j}{\pi n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2k}{\pi n}\right)$$
which can be easily evaluated (in [explicit terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Other_relations)) through [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Nice thought, could you be more explicit?

Comment: @George: you just have to use the identities listed on Wikipedia ("*Other Identities*") to compute the shown sum.

Comment: I'll try to go on, thanks for your help anyway, I am trying to understand

Comment: actually I can't find the identities

Comment: @George: right after *In this form, the simple identities given above take the form*

Comment: It's a seldom encountered pleasure in these days to see a post of thee; I hope it will continue like this, since I really appreciate (and currently miss) your posts! (+1)